# xmlsec not installing on mac

Tags: python, flask, saml-2.0, xmlsec

I'm trying to use pysaml2 to integrate AWS's SSO into my flask application, pysaml2 requires xmlsec, but I'm having trouble installing it.

Here the error im getting:

```
pip install xmlsec
Collecting xmlsec
  Using cached xmlsec-1.3.13.tar.gz (64 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: lxml>=3.8 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from xmlsec) (4.9.3)
Building wheels for collected packages: xmlsec
  Building wheel for xmlsec (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for xmlsec (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [13 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/xmlsec
      copying src/xmlsec/py.typed -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/xmlsec
      copying src/xmlsec/tree.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/xmlsec
      copying src/xmlsec/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/xmlsec
      copying src/xmlsec/constants.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/xmlsec
      copying src/xmlsec/template.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/xmlsec
      running build_ext
      error: Unable to invoke pkg-config.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for xmlsec
Failed to build xmlsec
ERROR: Could not build wheels for xmlsec, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have installed homebrew and installed libxml2, libxmlsec1, and pkg-config. However the issue is still there. Does anyone know a solution?

I've also tried solutions from other stack overflow questions, but they did not entirely match my case, and they did not work.

Comment: what are the version of libxmlsec1 libxml2 installed in your system?

Comment: @sahasrara62 Here are the versions:
libxml2: 2.9.13
libxmlsec1: 1.3.1

Comment: it does not support python 3.11 , use 3.9 instead

Answer (score 0):

1. Check `pkg-config` Access: Ensure `pkg-config` is in your PATH.

```
 which pkg-config
```

If nothing returns, it's not in your PATH.

2. Set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`:
   Before installation, set the path:

```
 export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/libxmlsec1/lib/pkgconfig"
 pip install xmlsec
```

3. Direct Installation with Logging:
   Get a detailed error by installing directly from the source:

```
git clone https://github.com/mehcode/python-xmlsec.git
cd python-xmlsec
pip install -v .
```

4. Use a Virtual Environment:
   Create an isolated Python environment and install within:

```
python -m venv myenv
source myenv/bin/activate
pip install xmlsec
```

5. Install Compiler Tools:

```
xcode-select --install
```